# windows phone 8 Is there a way to read file downloaded from computer inside an app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I faced the problem to get data from PC. I have a file with text on my PC and I want to read this text in my app. Google said that WP8 has closed file system and that's why I can't just copy file to documents and read it from app. I looked to onedrive option but it's too complicated to me and I still don't know if I can read files from onedrive. Can this problem be solved somehow? Is there a way to read files in apps downloaded from computer?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I know of is to do something like this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj720573(v=vs.105).aspx) to read a file from an SD Card. Otherwise you could go the OneDrive route. You can read and write to files on a user's OneDrive as long as they sign in to give you permissions to their OneDrive account. You can implement this by using the [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/dn632140).